# the difference of const initializer for global and local variable in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, initialization

I'm not sure why the error happened. However, in the following line the code is OK when compiling.

Does someone have any explanation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int g_value = 10;
const int* p1 = &g_value;
const int* p2 = p1; // error: initializer element is not constant
int main()
{
    const int* p3 = &g_value;
    const int* p4 = p3; // Compile normally without any error!
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the rules for initializers of block-scope variables are different from the rules for initializers of file-scope variables.  The former are required to be constant expressions, as C defines that term.  The latter are not.  In the code given, `p1` is not a constant expression.

Comment: Could you give me more details? Or some links about this topic :-)

Comment: Have you considered simply pasting the error message into your search bar and seeing what your favorite search engine will tell you?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, it's really the storage duration that matters.

Comment: Yes, @IanAbbott, that is true.  If I intended to post an actual answer to this question then I would be more careful there.

Comment: The `const` is a bit of a red-herring here. You can remove the `const` qualifiers from the file-scope variables and it will still fail.